# How to show a some text when Table component is empty

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report who call a subreport. This subreport have a table using dataset.

I want to display a message when I have no record in my table. How to do this?

Comment: I already use "When No Data" but my query is in dataset not in global query on my subreport. Or maybe there is something I don't know yet.

Comment: remember that you need to set  whenNoDataType to noData on the subreports (jasperReport tag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "fake" *staticText* with text you want (*No data* text, for example) behind the *Table* component in cooperantion with removed ***whenNoDataType*** property of *Table* component should solve this task.

#### Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_27" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="95f68ce4-441a-425c-88fb-b48fe96fac6b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Empty Dataset1" uuid="21916aaf-ceb1-456b-a45e-6c31863ac208"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="252" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="555" height="35" uuid="ff8a82ab-c00f-422a-a907-06d4021b87bd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No data]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="200" uuid="1a91c926-a553-4eab-bc04-938c1a962f9a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Empty Dataset1" uuid="1834081e-7aa0-4719-a0ac-e077f259cc18">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="555" uuid="eb741b0d-640c-48d1-b653-03703ce9e27e">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30"/>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

In *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) the design looks like:

[image: Design in Studio]

#### Output result

If we applied ***"All Section No Detail"*** value for Table's dataset (**whenNoDataType** property):

- in *JSS* this settings can be set with *"When No Data Type"* combobox:

[image: GUI for setting property]

- or in *jrxml*

```xml
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
```

The result of showing empty Table will be:

[image: Preview in JSS]

In case deleting this property (**whenNoDataType** is NULL) the result will be:

[image: Preview in JSS]

in this case the *Table* tag at *jrxml* will be:

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
```

Comment: Oh really good!! it works !! Thank you !! But I have a last question. I use subreport do show different table and with your solution I have something like that:
![Valid XHTML](http://hpics.li/74d8e53).
It's a line and I don't know how I can remove her if I have no result.